# Scope of loader class in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, inheritance

I am confused about what is the scope of loader class. I mean we can use $this->load->library('library_name') to load library. But when it comes to multi-level inheritance, it is not working as expected.

For eg. I have multi-level in inheritance in my project.

'Mysite' controller that extends 'CI_Controller' class.
'Parent' controller that extends 'Mysite' class/controller.
'Child' controller that extends 'Parent' controller.

In Child class if I use, $this->load->library('library_name'), it is not working, and throwing the error that undefined variable.

Can anyone please tell why this behavior? Also possible solution for this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a `__call()` method declared in any of those classes?

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling `parent::_construct()` in the constructor of the child classes? You need to call that to add the CI "instance" to the class scope.

Comment: First, thanks for your reply. Yes, I am calling that, but still the problem is there.